# xml schema: keyref to multiple keys?

Tags: xml

I am learning xml schema and I found some problem I can not solve. Here is part of my schema

```
    <xsd:key name="States">
        <xsd:selector xpath="state"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:key name="States_i">
        <xsd:selector xpath="initial"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:keyref name="TransitionsToState" refer="States">
        <xsd:selector xpath="state/transition"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:keyref>
```

I want to make some kind of union on keys "States" and "States_i" so i can refer to them in keyref. Basically the transition should be either id from "initial" or id from "state". Is this possible?

Comment: Solution would be nearly easy with your XML element structure. As long both have an `id` attribute you can join them in the `xpath`  of your `key` and use them then in your `keyref`.
`<xsd:key name="States.States_i"><xsd:selector xpath="state|initial"/><xsd:field xpath="@id"/></xsd:key>`

`<xsd:keyref name="TransitionsToState" refer="States.States_i"><xsd:selector xpath="state/transition"/><xsd:field xpath="."/></xsd:keyref>`